# All Media Query's working but one

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

I checked all other questions regarding media query's and they didn't seem to be same issue(or) maybe its cause I'm a rookie.

Anyway, I have 4 media query's. For the most part they just shrink the margin as a desktop window gets smaller(till you get to mobile). Flex boxes do the rest.

As you shrink the window. Media query's hit the 1st,2nd, and 4th query skipping over the 3rd. Can anyone see an issue with the css? Broken one: -->

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1289px) and (min-width: 401) {

    @media screen and (min-width: 1950px) {

       .header {
            margin-left: 20em;
            margin-right: 20em;
        }

        .container {
            margin-left: 20em;
            margin-right: 20em;
        }

        .footer {
            margin-left: 20em;
            margin-right: 20em;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1949px) and (min-width: 1290px) {

       .header {
            margin-left: 5em;
            margin-right: 5em;
        }

        .container {
            margin-left: 5em;
            margin-right: 5em;
        }

        .footer {
            margin-left: 5em;
            margin-right: 5em;
        }
        .item{background-color: blue;}
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1289px) and (min-width: 401) {

       .header {
            margin-left: 0em;
            margin-right: 0em;
        }

        .container {
            margin-left: 0em;
            margin-right: 0em;
        }

        .item {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: red;
        }

        .footer {
            margin-left: 0em;
            margin-right: 0em;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 400px) { 

          #body {
            font-size: 3.0em;
        }

        .header {
            margin-right: 0em;
            margin-left: 0em;
        }

        .container {
           margin-right: 0em;
           margin-left: 0em;
        }
          .item {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .footer {
           margin-right: 0em;
           margin-left: 0em;
           font-size: .3em;
        }

        .tab {
            height: 10vh;  
        }

        .option {
            width: 125px;
            height: 125px;
        }
         .specifications-table {
            margin-top: 0em;
        }

        .table-header{
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }

        .spec-label {
            font-size: 1em;
        }

        .spec-option {
            font-size: 1em;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        .disclosure{
            max-width: 100%;
            font-size: .35em;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hm, `min-width: 401`...sure you didn't mean `min-width: 401px` or something?

Comment: That is so embarrassing ha-ha.  Thank you very much!! - that fixed it.

Comment: Glad to help out! Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes. =P

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have added the code formatted for the code which you have written. Please see the editing help for more information on formatting.  Good luck!